# How does this function invocation pattern work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Reading the book "Node.js Design Patterns" , on the page 78, I found the following code:

```
var tasks = [...];
var concurrency = 2, running = 0, completed = 0, index = 0;

function next() {

    while(running < concurrency && index < tasks.length) {
        task = tasks[index++];

        task(function() {                     // THE ISSUE IS HERE!!!
            if(completed === tasks.length) {
                return finish();
            }
            completed++, running--;
            next();
        });                                  // THE END OF MY ISSUE
    running++;
    }
}
next();

function finish() {
   //all tasks finished
}
```

So I can't understand what the snippet `task(function(){...});` does mean. Intersted the syntax as itself. How this style is called? May be some shorthand or, for example, "passing function as a parameter (or method) to the object"? And where I can read about this syntax? I found nothing.

Comment: I'd start by doing a google search for "JavaScript callback functions".

Comment: Why do you think `task` is an object. It all looks like it is just a function that takes a callback. Nothing fancy.

Comment: it's not much different from the `next()` line. it's just calling a function with a parameter.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko To be fair though, functions ARE objects in JS

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Absolutely! Why else would I hang around Stackoverflow?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm To help people I guess. :)

Comment: All is true. The object that creates the tasks was created using the constructor "function", as written further. So it's just passing the function as a parameter to the higher function. I still would not understand without you all. GREAT THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

A function that accepts another function as an argument is known as a [Higher Order Function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

I wouldn't call it a "syntax". It's more of a technique to create more generalized code.

In this case, the function being passed is likely a callback that will be executed at a later time. This is fairly common in (but not specific to) Javascript due to how often asynchronous code is used.